# XSLT Multiple level grouping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm a beginner is xslt and have been fighting with an issue for some time now:

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<root>
<record>
    <column name="LVL1">16080503</column>
    <column name="LVL2">123</column>
    <column name="LVL3">R08050003</column>
    <column name="TOP">ABC</column>
</record>

<record>
      <column name="LVL1">16080504</column>
      <column name="LVL2">123</column>
      <column name="LVL3">R08050004</column>
      <column name="TOP">DEF</column>
</record>

<record>
      <column name="LVL1">16080523</column>
      <column name="LVL2">123</column>
      <column name="LVL3">R08050023</column>
      <column name="TOP">ABC</column>
</record>

<record>
      <column name="LVL1">16080909</column>
      <column name="LVL2">456</column>
      <column name="LVL3">A08090340</column>
      <column name="TOP">ABC</column>
</record>

<record>
      <column name="LVL1">16080503</column>
      <column name="LVL2">123</column>
      <column name="LVL3">R08050006</column>
      <column name="TOP">ABC</column>
</record>

<record>
      <column name="LVL1">00732544</column>
      <column name="LVL2">123</column>
      <column name="LVL3">R02713691</column>
      <column name="TOP">ABC</column>
</record>

<record>
      <column name="LVL1">00732544</column>
      <column name="LVL2">123</column>
      <column name="LVL3">RC02713691</column>
      <column name="TOP">DEF</column>
</record>
</root>
```

This is stripped down from a more complex one, but it should still make sense.
I need to use xslt to have it look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<File>
        <LVL0>ABC</LVL0>
        <Group>
            <LVL1>16080503</LVL1>
            <SubGroups>
                <SubGroup>
                    <LVL2>123</LVL2>
                    <XXXs>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>R08050003</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>R08050006</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                    </XXXs>
                </SubGroup>
            </SubGroups>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <LVL1>16080523</LVL1>
            <SubGroups>
                <SubGroup>
                    <LVL2>123</LVL2>
                    <XXXs>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>R08050023</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                    </XXXs>
                </SubGroup>
            </SubGroups>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <LVL1>16080909</LVL1>
            <SubGroups>
                <SubGroup>
                    <LVL2>451</LVL2>
                    <XXXs>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>A08090340</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                    </XXXs>
                </SubGroup>
            </SubGroups>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <LVL1>00732544</LVL1>
            <SubGroups>
                <SubGroup>
                    <LVL2>123</LVL2>
                    <XXXs>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>R02713691</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                    </XXXs>
                </SubGroup>
            </SubGroups>
        </Group>
    </File>
<File>
        <LVL0>DEF</LVL0>
        <Group>
            <LVL1>16080504</LVL1>
            <SubGroups>
                <SubGroup>
                    <LVL2>123</LVL2>
                    <XXXs>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>R08050004</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                    </XXXs>
                </SubGroup>
            </SubGroups>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <LVL1>00732544</LVL1>
            <SubGroups>
                <SubGroup>
                    <LVL2>123</LVL2>
                    <XXXs>
                        <XXX>
                            <LVL3>RC02713691</LVL3>
                        </XXX>
                    </XXXs>
                </SubGroup>
            </SubGroups>
        </Group>
</File>
```

I've been researching multiple ways to do this and I'm not sure which would be best; using `<xsl:for-each>` or `<xsl:apply-templates>`. 
I'd rather do it using templates as I'm more familiar with them, but I'm kind of stuck.

I think I should be using this key for the top level grouping, but again I'm not getting the desired results;

```
<xsl:key name="key1" match="record/column[@name='TOP']" use="."/>
```

Any help in explaining the logic to be used in this type of issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200101/msg00070.html. I would start with `<xsl:key name="key1" match="record" use="column[@name='TOP']"/>` and `<xsl:key name="key2" match="record" use="concat(column[@name='TOP'], '|',column[@name='LVL1'])" />`.

Comment: Thank you for the link, this was very useful. Once I got the path right the grouping went great, every deeper key incorporating the key from the level above it.